# HTML links in XML Driven Skitter

Tags: xml

I'm using the Skitter slider with the XML loading option, but I need to make the images/slides clickable links. Is there a way to do that in the XML?

Here's the Source code.
http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/?type_loading=xml

Answer (score 0):

After some resourceful searching, you can add a link in the Skitter xml file with a single line of code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<skitter>
    <slide>
        <link>http://foo.com</link>
        <image type="directionTop">images/bar.jpg</image>
    </slide>
</skitter>
```

That's all there is to it.